# Using R - Converting vector from a table to another table

Tags: r, vector, input, expression

I am doing some batch processing of graphs and having an issue with locating another table from a string.

```
# Source table

t<-read.csv(file="Results.csv",header=TRUE)

# Graph Input

g<-read.csv(file="Graphs.csv",header=TRUE)
```

The graph input has a list of all the graphs I want to produce and the source table has all the data in it:

```
y<-paste(g[1,1])
x<-paste(g[1,2])
```

The vectors of `x` is `t$mass` and `y` is `t$luminosity` where the data for `mass` and `luminosity` are in the table `t`. However, if I type `y`, I just get the vector or expression `"t$luminosity"` rather than the table with the data values.

How do I make it call the correct information?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a workaround with the aes_string function from ggplot2:

```
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
x <- str_replace(x, "t[$]", "")
y <- str_replace(y, "t[$]", "")
ggplot(data=t) + geom_point(aes_string(x=x, y=y)
```

Comment: Ah ok thanks for responding so quickly. There is no possible way it would work with the using the plot function then? I've tried changing

x<-as.name(x)

But t$x returns NULL unfortunately.